# User validation with ClickOnce installer?

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, clickonce

I am creating a WPF windows desktop application. 
I need to do some validation, while installation of the application, if the validation fails i need to stop the installation, else complete the installation.

**Can this be achieved in Click Once?**

I found this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx for creating a custom installer. But it requires to create a seperate application and use the custom installer class to install the application.
Is it possible to override the default installer?

Comment: What kind of validation?

Comment: I need to check the user authentication based on his windows credentials.

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to just validate credentials on app startup and just not allow the user to use the application if they are not a valid user. This is typically how things are done. (i.e. at my work we use IBM Process Designer, which is only meant for certain people, but anyone can install they just won'y be able to use it if they don't have authorization)

Comment: If you need to validate things like "does the user have .NET 4.0 installed?" or something else that is required for the application to run at all then you would do that in an installer.

Comment: The reason I need to do this is the people who use this application will not have internet access and it is only during installation that they will be connected to the internet. 
And the users need to provide path from which my application can download data. And i need to be able to do this at the time of installation.

Comment: You can write your own installer that does the authentication, obviously you have to make your own start menu shortcuts, etc.

Comment: How about disallowing of the install url rather than in the install? Turn off anonymous authentication and turn on windows authentication so that you know who the user is, and redirect if it's not right set of users.

Comment: I cant do that, because I get the list of valid users from database. And the installation should be done only if the user is a valid user.

Comment: If this is an company internal application, why don't you just use a UNC path publishing method instead of over the internet? This would allow you to put all windows user accounts into one group and only allow them to access the directory. It's a similar approach to @JoelLucsy one, but more secure for your company.

Comment: It is an internal application but the user roles are decided by an admin who adds it to the db. And i can get that details from DB from the application.

Comment: If you want to stick to ClickOnce, then you'll have to use a custom installer you linked in your question. This is more or less, an override of the custom installer/extending it's functionality. You cannot modify the real ClickOnce behavior.

Comment: Please try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480721.aspx#adminc_topic10

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way you can do something like that with ClickOnce is using the customer installer that you have already found.

I would recommend doing any kind of validation against the authenticated user at install time because 2 users could use the same machine, one who is allowed to install and one who is not.  The user who is allowed to install could do so, and the user who is not could then run it.

It's much better to authenticate users when your app is run as mclaassen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can split installation into two steps.

First make a standard installation for full application, lets call installation A.

Develop an application that read permission from DB and, if is a valid user, runs installation A, if not, run uninstall.

Make an standar installation for this new permission checker application, and make it run this aplication after install.

Comment: It could be a console application retrieving parameters from command line. No user interaction needed.